# How to turn a flutter function into a stateless class?

Tags: function, flutter, widget

I'm following Angela Yu's flutter beginner tutorials, and I couldn't figure out how to turn a function into a stateless class and use it inside a widget.

I've done it before with a simple Container or Column, but I couldn't grasp the concept with the following example:

```
class _PriceScreenState extends State<PriceScreen> {
  String selectedCurrency = 'USD';

  List<DropdownMenuItem> getDropdownItems() {
    List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> dropdownItems = [];

    for (String currency in currenciesList) {
      var newItem = DropdownMenuItem(
        child: Text(currency),
        value: currency,
      );
      dropdownItems.add(newItem);
    }
    return dropdownItems;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: DropdownButton<String>(
            value: selectedCurrency,
            items: getDropdownItems(),
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                selectedCurrency = value;
              });
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

How would you turn the function, getDropdownItems(), into a separate stateless class and use it inside the widget?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is not to turn `List<DropdownMenuItem>` into a `StatelessWidget`, but instead to make a stateless widget for the list item

It's a matter of changing

```dart
DropdownButton<String>(
  value: selectedCurrency,
  items: [
    for (String currency in currenciesList)
      DropdownMenuItem(
        child: Text(currency),
        value: currency,
      ),
  ],
  onChanged: (value) {
    setState(() {
      selectedCurrency = value;
    });
  },
),
```

into:

```dart
DropdownButton<String>(
  value: selectedCurrency,
  items: [
    for (String currency in currenciesList)
      MyStatelessWidget(currency: currency),
  ],
  onChanged: (value) {
    setState(() {
      selectedCurrency = value;
    });
  },
),

...

class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyStatelessWidget({Key key, this.currency}) : super(key: key);

  final String currency;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownMenuItem(
      value: currency,
      child: Text(currency),
    );
  }
}
```